# AngularJS ui-select - apply filter while searching

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate, ui-select

I am implementing i18n with https://angular-translate.github.io/ and I also use ui-select.

When I have a select for ["FOO", "BAR"], and I want to translate those values I can:

```
<ui-select ng-model="myModel">
   <ui-select-match>
     <span ng-bind="$select.selected | translate"></span>
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (myList | filter: $select.search)">
     <span ng-bind="item | translate"></span>
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The problem is when I want to filter the values. Let's say I translate FOO to BANANA and BAR to ORANGE.

If I type "BA", "ORANGE" shows up because it is filtering ["FOO", "BAR"], not ["BANANA", "ORANGE"].

Also, I can't change the list because I want to have FOO and BAR on my model.

How can I filter the values of **myList** to translate if before searching for values?

Comment: Can you make a previous "treatment" to `myList` before showing it in the ui-select? I'm asking because you could get the i18ns before rendering the values, update the list and then search on the i18n. I do not know if I'm I making myself clear.

Comment: You can make a custom filter that does the translate before looking for a match.

Comment: @shaunhusain your comment helped me. I can chain filters so that I can translate the list before querying it. If you can, post as an answer so I can flag it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a custom filter can allow you to chain the filters in order to get the desired filtered list:

```
.filter('myLangFilter', function(translationDict){
  return function(input){
    return input.map(function(cur) { return translationDict[cur]?translationDict[cur]:cur; })
  }
})
```

Then to chain in your custom filter could do something like:

```
item in (myList | myLangFilter | filter: $select.search)
```

Comment: I just tried this approach, but what happens is that the translated value ends up in my model, but I want the value before it is translated.